# Centering TikZ picture horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, vertical-alignment

I've got some figures I'd like to use, but since the first one is larger than the second, the second gets placed relative to the lower edge of the first one.
My code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (6, 0) node[right] {$z$};
    \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 6) node[above] {$x$};
    \coordinate (a) at (5, 1);
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$s$}] (s) at (5, 5) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=below:{$e$}] (e) at (1, 1) {};
    \draw (s) -- (e);
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$m^*$}] (m*) at (2.293, 3.707) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=right:{$m$}] (m) at (3, 3) {};
    \draw (m) -- (m*);
    \draw[dashed] (s) -- (a) node[pos=0.5, label=right:{$\Delta x$}] -- (e) node[pos=0.5, label=below:{$\Delta z$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{10mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}        
    \coordinate (ayy) at (4.293, 1);
    \coordinate (mstar) at (4.293, 3.707);
    \coordinate (emm) at (7, 1);
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$m^*$}] (m*) at (mstar) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=right:{$m$}] (m) at (emm) {};
    \node[fill=none, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (a) at (ayy) {};
    \draw (m) -- (m*) node[pos=0.6, label=right:{$d$}] {};
    \draw[dashed] (a) -- (m*) node[pos=0.5, label=left:{$d\cos\alpha$}] {};
    \draw[dashed] (a) -- (m) node[pos=0.5, label=below:{$d\sin\alpha$}] {};
    \pic[draw, "$\alpha$", angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=7mm] {angle=ayy--mstar--emm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Calculating $m^*$ (Case 1)}
\end{figure}
```

What I currently have:
[image: What I have]

What I'd like to get:
[image: What I'd like to get]:

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please, give a fully compileable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! There are many ways, out of which I illustrate two:

1. Use `\vcenter`. The perhaps simplest way to use it is to put it in math mode.
2. Use only one picture and work with scopes.

In the second example, I simplified the code a bit by using polar coordinates, use the parser to parse coordinates, combine paths, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
$\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (6, 0) node[right] {$z$};
    \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 6) node[above] {$x$};
    \coordinate (a) at (5, 1);
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$s$}] (s) at (5, 5) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=below:{$e$}] (e) at (1, 1) {};
    \draw (s) -- (e);
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$m^*$}] (m*) at (2.293, 3.707) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=right:{$m$}] (m) at (3, 3) {};
    \draw (m) -- (m*);
    \draw[dashed] (s) -- (a) node[pos=0.5, label=right:{$\Delta x$}]{}
     -- (e) node[pos=0.5, label=below:{$\Delta z$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\hspace{10mm}
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (ayy) at (4.293, 1);
    \coordinate (mstar) at (4.293, 3.707);
    \coordinate (emm) at (7, 1);
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$m^*$}] (m*) at (mstar) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=right:{$m$}] (m) at (emm) {};
    \node[fill=none, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (a) at (ayy) {};
    \draw (m) -- (m*) node[pos=0.6, label=right:{$d$}] {};
    \draw[dashed] (a) -- (m*) node[pos=0.5, label=left:{$d\cos\alpha$}] {};
    \draw[dashed] (a) -- (m) node[pos=0.5, label=below:{$d\sin\alpha$}] {};
    \pic[draw, "$\alpha$", angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=7mm] {angle=ayy--mstar--emm};
\end{tikzpicture}}}$
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=#1}]
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.9]
    \draw[<->] (0, 6) node[above] {$x$} |- (6, 0) node[right] {$z$};
    \coordinate (a) at (5, 1);
    \node[bullet=above:{$s$}] (s) at (5, 5) {};
    \node[bullet=below:{$e$}] (e) at (1, 1) {};
    \draw (s) -- node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=right:{$m$}] (m){}  (e)
        (m) ++ (135:1) 
        node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=above:{$m^*$}] (m*) {};
    \draw (m) -- (m*);
    \draw[dashed] (s) |- (e) node[pos=0.75,below] {$\Delta z$}
    node[pos=0.25,right](dx){$\Delta x$};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path (dx)  ++ (3,{-1-1/sqrt(8)})  coordinate (a)
        ++ (0,{2+1/sqrt(2)}) 
        node[bullet=above:{$m^*$}] (m*) {}
        (a) ++ ({2+1/sqrt(2)},0)
        node[bullet=right:{$m$}] (m){};
    \draw (m) -- (m*);  
    \draw[dashed] (m*)  --  node[left] (dc){$d\cos\alpha$} (a)
        -- node[below]{$d\sin\alpha$} (m);
    \pic[draw, "$\alpha$", angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=7mm] 
    {angle=a--m*--m};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, the usual format on this site is to provide complete minimal working examples (MWEs). These are codes that contain everything needed to be compiled, and start typically with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. In your case, I do not know what document class you are using, so I had to guess, and which packages you are loading (beyond those needed to make your snippet run through). You may very well already load something that has tools to solve your problem in another way.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I'll be sure to include packages and document class next time. I also realized I meant vertical centering and not horizontal as stated in the title, but you figured that out too.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is align images at selected baseline . For example, with slightly modified code for images, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                calc, % new
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \tikzset{dot/.style = {circle, fill=red, minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt}}% new
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.center)] % <---
% caxes
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6, 0) node[right] {$z$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0, 6) node[above] {$x$};
% triangle
\node (s) [dot, label=$s$]          at (5,5) {};
\node (e) [dot, label=below:{$e$}]  at (1,1) {};
\draw (s) -- node (m) [dot, label=right:$m$] {} (e);
\node (m*) [dot, label=$m^*$] at ($(m)!10mm!90:(s)$) {};
    \node[fill=red, circle, scale=0.3, label=right:{$m$}] (m) at (3, 3) {};
\draw (m) -- (m*);
\draw[dashed] (e) -| (s) node[pos=0.25, label=below:$\Delta z$] {}
                         node (X) [pos=0.75, label=right:$\Delta x$] {}; % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
    \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.center)] % <---
\node (m*) [dot, label=above:$m^*$] {};
\node (m)  [dot, label=right:$m$]   at (3,-3) {};
\draw (m*) -- node[label=right:$d$] {} (m);
\draw[dashed] (m*) |- (m)   node (X) [pos=0.25, label=left:$d\cos\alpha$] {} % <---
                            coordinate[pos=0.5] (a)  % <--- 
                            node[pos=0.75, label=below:$d\sin\alpha$] {};
\pic[draw, "$\alpha$", angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=7mm] {angle=a--m*--m};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\caption{Calculating $m^*$ (Case 1)}
\end{document}
```

[image]